# Set all values in SelectList in C#

Tags: c#, selectlist

In a `SelectList` object, I want that the Text property of each element of the SelectList should also be the value. For eg:

```
SelectList s=new SelectList(some list);
s.ElementAt(i).Value=s.ElementAt(i).Text;
```

Is there any way to do this APART from using a loop? Is there any inbuilt method or something like that to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Constructor overload for SelectList:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

You can then, provided same list member for dataValueField and dataTextField.

Comment: You mean like : new SelectList(some list, "Text", "Text");

Comment: Can you inform how is your list like? Is it like List<string> or what?

Comment: @karank : yes, exactly  new SelectList(some list, "Text", "Text"); should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it without a loop, just use linq foreach (which is a loop in the background):

```
s.ToList().ForEach(c=>c.Text = c.Value)
```

Comment: He said, he does'nt want to loop through the list.

Comment: @ebad86 That's why I suggested linq