# What is available in the controller from a post action in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selectlist

Trying to unpack some inherited code and I am new to ASP.NET.  My question:

**What is available in the controller from a post action in a dropdownlist in C# (ASP.NET MVC5)?**

Here is what I have in the view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Location", FormMethod.Post))
 ....
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
 model => model.Member.PillarId, new SelectList (Model.Pillars, "Id", "Title"))
```

Here is the `MemberViewModel`:

```
 public class MemberViewModel : IValidatableObject{
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public int? PillarId { get; set; }  
     }
```

Here is the `Member` model:

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }   

    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public int? PillarId { get; set; }
    public String PillarTitle { get; set; }
```

Here is the `Member` model constructor(s):

```
    public Member() { }
    public Member(MemberViewModel member)
    { 
        PillarId = member.PillarId;
        ///
    }
```

Here is the Controller

```
 public ActionResult SignUp(MemberViewModel member){///}
```

My form is correctly pulling the information from the DB to display, as well as posting correctly to the DB via the Controller. I do not want to change the visual options for the user to choose from (i.e. I think ListBox is out?).

Rather, I want to assign both `Member.PillarId` as well as the `Member.Title` based on their choice and have it available in the `Controller` for non-DB operations.

What is currently available in the `SignUp` method in the `Controller`? Can I call `Model.Pillars.Title`? Is it `member.PillarId.Pillars.Id`? If not, how can I assign it dynamically based on the user choice?

There are views and modelviews flying around in this code, and I am not sure what is available...

SO has a bunch of answers on the DropDownList, so here's a sampling of articles that are somewhat related to what I am getting at...
* [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242981/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-from-selectlist/20243119#20243119)
* [ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824638/select-multiple-value-in-dropdownlist-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp)
* [ListBoxFor: not MVC dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12177100/3100284)
* [SelectList Constructor: Not MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203018/3100284)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you expecting to get the values of both `PillarId` and `PillarTitle` when you select an item from the dropdownlist?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am getting PillarId. I need PillarTitle. Yes, I would like both.

Comment: A `<select>` posts back a single value (the value of the selected option) or an array of values if `multiple`. If you want the selected display text, then get it from the repository when you post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a dropdownlist the only value that will come back is the value of the selected item when posting back.

If you want something else to come back you would need a hidden field on the page and bind a change event listener to the dropdown to set the title in the hidden field

```
public class MemberViewModel : IValidatableObject{
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public int? PillarId { get; set; }  
    public string Title { get; set;}
}
```

---

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Location", FormMethod.Post))
 ....
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
 model => model.Member.PillarId, new SelectList (Model.Pillars, "Id", "Title"))
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Title);
```

***javascript***

```
 $('#idofdropdown').on('change', function()
  {
     var selectedTitle = $(this).find(":selected").text();
     $('#Title').val(selectedTitle);
  });
```

**How to get selected title from a drop down list:** [Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)

Then in your controller your viewmodel will have the title text inside the     Title string :)